# Perform timed graphic animation in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, animation, user-interface, windows-phone-8

So here's my problem : I'm currently creating the graphical interface for a windows phone 8 app (silverlight app) and in one page, when a button is clicked, the code behind performs an action and to show the user that the action is taking place, there is a small animation in the middle of the screen.

The animation consists of a B&W image becoming a color image. To do that, I placed two images in the same place in my app, the grey is in front of the colored one, and the opacity of the colored one is set to 0%

When the user clicks the button, this function is called :

```
private void set_opacity()
    {
        int i;
        i = 0;
        while (i<=10)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(i);
            colored_logo.Opacity += 0.1;
            bw_logo.Opacity -= 0.1;
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            i = i + 1;
        }
    }
```

I know a "for" loop would have been better, I tried with the for loop at first but had the same problem : nothing happens during the 2 seconds of the while loop, and at the end of these 2 seconds, the image suddenly goes from b&w to color

Maybe there is another method, I'd just like to have a  smooth transition from b&w to color, during approx. 2 seconds

Comment: Please delete all that horrible code and start reading about [Animations in XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742868(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN. BTW, if your application is performing a time-consuming task, such task should be executed in a **background thread** in order not to keep the UI thread busy and "freeze" the UI. Read about [asynchronous programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone apps are by default single-threaded.  So, while you're running that code, the UI is blocked and cannot perform any updates.  There is a special timer object called [`DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.95).aspx) that is useful for scenarios where you want to perform rapid periodic UI updates -- without blocking.  Basically, you would just put your "while" code inside the dispatcher's tick delegate.

However, while you could use a `DispatcherTimer`, there is an easier way: there is an entire infrastructure in XAML for performing animations.  You can define storyboards and control them entirely within markup.  Just as an example, here is roughly the equivalent of what you're trying to do (start a cross-fade animation when the user clicks a button):

```
<StackPanel xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
            xmlns:em="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Media;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"
            >
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="FadeLogoStoryboard" Duration="0:0:2">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="colored_logo" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             To="1" Duration="0:0:2" />
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bw_logo" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             To="0" Duration="0:0:2" />
        </Storyboard>
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="colored_logo" ... Opacity="0" />
        <Image x:Name="bw_logo" ... Opacity="1" />
    </Grid>

    <Button Content="Start Animation">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <em:ControlStoryboardAction ControlStoryboardOption="Play"
                                            Storyboard="{StaticResource FadeLogoStoryboard}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

(Note that I used the [Blend SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd440763.aspx) to trigger the Storyboard, but there are other ways to do that.)

Comment: I get an error with the xaml inside the <button> brackets (the code about triggering the event)
From what it says, it seems like expression/2010/interactivity doesn't exist or isn't used anymore
Do you know where this error comes from ? Maybe I made a mistake ? (But I did reference Microsoft.Expressions.Interactions in my project so I don't think that's the problem)